# FreeBSD not rebooting [alone]

Tags: freebsd

I have setup here a FreeBSD 11.1 32 bits in an old PC, an Asus eeePC 900 for testing purposes.

The machine works quite well, except that it hangs at shutdown time, either using shutdown -r or halt. Curiously enough, if I press random keys, it goes on, so I suspect it is a matter of lack of entropy.

When shutting down, it says:

```
Stopping devd
Writing entropy file: .
Writing early boot: .
Terminated
. Aug  6 16:08:55 xxxxx syslogd: exiting on signal 15
```

Often it stops right here, sometimes after a few seconds it goes on. I have often to press shift here.

Then it goes on and displays:

```
Waiting (max 60 seconds) for system process vnlru to stop... done
Waiting (max 60 seconds) for system process bufdaemon to stop...
```

(and hangs here for good unless I press a key). Then it also goes on

```
Waiting (max 60 seconds) for system process syncer to stop...
Syncing disks, vnodes remaining... 3 1
```

I also locks here frequently...when I press keys, it then goes on and finishes the reboot.

(About the pauses, I already left it more than 5-10 minutes waiting on that pauses...)

I already installed hs-entropy with no apparent changes. (is it doing anything at all?) what can I do more?

The machine itself is not terribly loaded; it is running Apache, two wifi cards for a routing test, ipfw, apache, hostapd, unbound, dnsmasq, ntpd, sshd.

vmstat output

```
procs  memory       page                    disks     faults         cpu
r b w  avm   fre   flt  re  pi  po    fr   sr ad0 da0   in    sy    cs us sy id
0 0 0 195M  405M  1225   0  13   0  1485    5   0   0  321 10138  2221  8 17 74
```

uptime

```
$ uptime
 4:57PM  up 3 mins, 1 users, load averages: 0.97, 0.70, 0.33
```

dmesg

```
# dmesg
Copyright (c) 1992-2017 The FreeBSD Project.
Copyright (c) 1979, 1980, 1983, 1986, 1988, 1989, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994
    The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
FreeBSD is a registered trademark of The FreeBSD Foundation.
FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE #0 r321309: Fri Jul 21 04:10:47 UTC 2017
    root@releng2.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC i386
FreeBSD clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final 297347) (based on LLVM 4.0.0)
VT(vga): resolution 640x480
CPU: Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor          900MHz (630.08-MHz 686-class CPU)
  Origin="GenuineIntel"  Id=0x6d8  Family=0x6  Model=0xd  Stepping=8
  Features=0xafe9fbff<FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,CLFLUSH,DTS,ACPI,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,SS,TM,PBE>
  AMD Features=0x100000<NX>
real memory  = 536870912 (512 MB)
avail memory = 485584896 (463 MB)
Event timer "LAPIC" quality 100
ACPI APIC Table: <A M I  OEMAPIC >
random: unblocking device.
ioapic0 <Version 2.0> irqs 0-23 on motherboard
Timecounter "TSC" frequency 630080304 Hz quality 800
taskqgroup_adjust failed cnt: 1 stride: 1 mp_ncpus: 1 smp_started: 0
taskqgroup_adjust failed cnt: 1 stride: 1 mp_ncpus: 1 smp_started: 0
random: entropy device external interface
kbd1 at kbdmux0
module_register_init: MOD_LOAD (vesa, 0xc10123d0, 0) error 19
nexus0
vtvga0: <VT VGA driver> on motherboard
cryptosoft0: <software crypto> on motherboard
acpi0: <A M I OEMRSDT> on motherboard
acpi0: Power Button (fixed)
cpu0: <ACPI CPU> on acpi0
attimer0: <AT timer> port 0x40-0x43 irq 0 on acpi0
Timecounter "i8254" frequency 1193182 Hz quality 0
Event timer "i8254" frequency 1193182 Hz quality 100
atrtc0: <AT realtime clock> port 0x70-0x71 irq 8 on acpi0
Event timer "RTC" frequency 32768 Hz quality 0
Timecounter "ACPI-safe" frequency 3579545 Hz quality 850
acpi_timer0: <24-bit timer at 3.579545MHz> port 0x808-0x80b on acpi0
acpi_ec0: <Embedded Controller: GPE 0x18> port 0x62,0x66 on acpi0
pcib0: <ACPI Host-PCI bridge> port 0xcf8-0xcff on acpi0
pci0: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib0
vgapci0: <VGA-compatible display> port 0xec00-0xec07 mem 0xf7f00000-0xf7f7ffff,0xd0000000-0xdfffffff,0xf7ec0000-0xf7efffff irq 16 at device 2.0 on pci0
agp0: <Intel 82915GM (915GM GMCH) SVGA controller> on vgapci0
agp0: aperture size is 256M, detected 7932k stolen memory
vgapci0: Boot video device
vgapci1: <VGA-compatible display> mem 0xf7f80000-0xf7ffffff at device 2.1 on pci0
hdac0: <Intel 82801F HDA Controller> mem 0xf7eb8000-0xf7ebbfff irq 16 at device 27.0 on pci0
pcib1: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> irq 16 at device 28.0 on pci0
pci1: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib1
pcib2: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> irq 17 at device 28.1 on pci0
pci2: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib2
ae0: <Attansic Technology Corp, L2 FastEthernet> mem 0xfbfc0000-0xfbffffff irq 17 at device 0.0 on pci2
ae0: Using MSI messages.
miibus0: <MII bus> on ae0
atphy0: <Atheros F2 10/100 PHY> PHY 0 on miibus0
atphy0:  none, 10baseT, 10baseT-FDX, 100baseTX, 100baseTX-FDX, auto
ae0: Ethernet address: 00:22:15:30:0b:54
pcib3: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> irq 18 at device 28.2 on pci0
pci3: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib3
ath0: <Atheros 5424/2424> mem 0xfbef0000-0xfbefffff irq 18 at device 0.0 on pci3
ath0: AR2425 mac 14.2 RF5424 phy 7.0
ath0: 2GHz radio: 0x0000; 5GHz radio: 0x00a2
uhci0: <Intel 82801FB/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6) USB controller USB-A> port 0xe400-0xe41f irq 23 at device 29.0 on pci0
uhci0: LegSup = 0x2f00
usbus0 on uhci0
uhci1: <Intel 82801FB/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6) USB controller USB-B> port 0xe480-0xe49f irq 19 at device 29.1 on pci0
uhci1: LegSup = 0x2f00
usbus1 on uhci1
uhci2: <Intel 82801FB/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6) USB controller USB-C> port 0xe800-0xe81f irq 18 at device 29.2 on pci0
uhci2: LegSup = 0x2f00
usbus2 on uhci2
uhci3: <Intel 82801FB/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6) USB controller USB-D> port 0xe880-0xe89f irq 16 at device 29.3 on pci0
uhci3: LegSup = 0x2f00
usbus3 on uhci3
ehci0: <Intel 82801FB (ICH6) USB 2.0 controller> mem 0xf7eb7c00-0xf7eb7fff irq 23 at device 29.7 on pci0
usbus4: EHCI version 1.0
usbus4 on ehci0
pcib4: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 30.0 on pci0
pci4: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib4
isab0: <PCI-ISA bridge> at device 31.0 on pci0
isa0: <ISA bus> on isab0
atapci0: <Intel ICH6M SATA150 controller> port 0x1f0-0x1f7,0x3f6,0x170-0x177,0x376,0xffa0-0xffaf at device 31.2 on pci0
ata0: <ATA channel> at channel 0 on atapci0
ata1: <ATA channel> at channel 1 on atapci0
acpi_lid0: <Control Method Lid Switch> on acpi0
acpi_button0: <Sleep Button> on acpi0
acpi_button1: <Power Button> on acpi0
acpi_tz0: <Thermal Zone> on acpi0
battery0: <ACPI Control Method Battery> on acpi0
acpi_acad0: <AC Adapter> on acpi0
atkbdc0: <Keyboard controller (i8042)> port 0x60,0x64 irq 1 on acpi0
atkbd0: <AT Keyboard> irq 1 on atkbdc0
kbd0 at atkbd0
atkbd0: [GIANT-LOCKED]
psm0: <PS/2 Mouse> irq 12 on atkbdc0
psm0: [GIANT-LOCKED]
psm0: model Generic PS/2 mouse, device ID 0
pmtimer0 on isa0
orm0: <ISA Option ROM> at iomem 0xc0000-0xcf7ff pnpid ORM0000 on isa0
ppc0: parallel port not found.
Timecounters tick every 1.000 msec
nvme cam probe device init
usbus0: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus1: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
hdacc0: <Realtek ALC662 HDA CODEC> at cad 0 on hdac0
hdaa0: <Realtek ALC662 Audio Function Group> at nid 1 on hdacc0
pcm0: <Realtek ALC662 (Analog 2.0+HP/2.0)> at nid 20,27 and 24,25 on hdaa0
ugen0.1: <Intel UHCI root HUB> at usbus0
uhub0: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus0
ugen1.1: <Intel UHCI root HUB> at usbus1
uhub1: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus1
usbus2: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus3: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
ugen2.1: <Intel UHCI root HUB> at usbus2
uhub2: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus2
ugen3.1: <Intel UHCI root HUB> at usbus3
uhub3: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus3
usbus4: 480Mbps High Speed USB v2.0
ugen4.1: <Intel EHCI root HUB> at usbus4
uhub4: <Intel EHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 2.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus4
uhub0: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub1: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub2: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub3: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
ada0 at ata1 bus 0 scbus1 target 0 lun 0
ada0: <SILICONMOTION SM223AC > ATA-4 device
ada0: Serial Number 56423912022817071094
ada0: 66.700MB/s transfers (UDMA4, PIO 512bytes)
ada0: 3815MB (7815024 512 byte sectors)
Trying to mount root from ufs:/dev/ada0s1a [rw]...
wlan0: Ethernet address: 00:15:af:c6:9e:9b
uhub4: 8 ports with 8 removable, self powered
ugen4.2: <Ralink 802.11 n WLAN> at usbus4
ugen4.3: <ENE UB6225> at usbus4
umass0 on uhub4
umass0: <ENE UB6225, class 0/0, rev 2.00/1.00, addr 3> on usbus4
umass0:  SCSI over Bulk-Only; quirks = 0xc100
umass0:2:0: Attached to scbus2
da0 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus2 target 0 lun 0
da0: <USB2.0 CardReader SD0 0100> Removable Direct Access SCSI device
da0: Serial Number 146030377350
da0: 40.000MB/s transfers
da0: 1876MB (3842048 512 byte sectors)
da0: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>
wlan0: link state changed to UP
ae0: link state changed to DOWN
run0 on uhub4
run0: <1.0> on usbus4
run0: MAC/BBP RT5592 (rev 0x0222), RF RT5592 (MIMO 2T2R), address 7c:dd:90:a5:f5:1a
wlan1: Ethernet address: 7c:dd:90:a5:f5:1a
run0: firmware RT3071 ver. 0.33 loaded
wlan1: ieee80211_new_state_locked: pending INIT -> SCAN transition lost
ipfw2 (+ipv6) initialized, divert loadable, nat loadable, default to deny, logging disabled
run0: firmware RT3071 ver. 0.33 loaded
```

ps ax

```
# ps ax 
PID TT  STAT    TIME COMMAND
  0  -  DLs  0:00.41 [kernel]
  1  -  ILs  0:00.01 /sbin/init --
  2  -  DL   0:00.00 [crypto]
  3  -  DL   0:00.00 [crypto returns]
  4  -  DL   0:00.04 [cam]
  5  -  DL   0:00.00 [sctp_iterator]
  6  -  DL   0:00.01 [rand_harvestq]
  7  -  DL   0:00.00 [soaiod1]
  8  -  DL   0:00.00 [soaiod2]
  9  -  DL   0:00.00 [soaiod3]
 10  -  DL   0:00.00 [audit]
 11  -  RL   0:37.74 [idle]
 12  -  WL   0:01.07 [intr]
 13  -  DL   0:00.03 [geom]
 14  -  DL   0:00.22 [usb]
 15  -  DL   0:00.01 [acpi_thermal]
 16  -  DL   0:00.00 [soaiod4]
 17  -  DL   0:00.00 [pagedaemon]
 18  -  DL   0:00.00 [vmdaemon]
 19  -  DL   0:00.00 [pagezero]
 20  -  DL   0:00.01 [bufdaemon]
 21  -  DL   0:00.00 [bufspacedaemon]
 22  -  DL   0:00.01 [syncer]
 23  -  DL   0:00.00 [vnlru]
121  -  Is   0:00.00 adjkerntz -i
301  -  Ss   0:00.01 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_suppli
445  -  Is   0:00.00 dhclient: wlan0 [priv] (dhclient)
491  -  Is   0:00.00 dhclient: wlan0 (dhclient)
576  -  Is   0:00.00 /sbin/devd
642  -  Is   0:00.00 /sbin/natd -dynamic -n wlan0
756  -  Ss   0:00.03 /usr/sbin/syslogd -s
775  -  Is   0:00.08 /usr/local/sbin/unbound
780  -  I    0:00.01 /usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq -x /var/run/dnsmasq.pid -C /usr/lo
879  -  Is   0:00.01 /usr/sbin/sshd
884  -  Ss   0:00.02 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
891  -  I    0:00.00 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
892  -  S    0:00.00 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
893  -  I    0:00.00 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
894  -  I    0:00.00 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
895  -  I    0:00.00 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
906  -  Ss   0:00.01 /usr/sbin/cron -s
939  -  Ss   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/hostapd -P /var/run/hostapd.pid -B /etc/hostapd.
970  -  Is   0:00.08 sshd: rui [priv] (sshd)
973  -  S    0:00.04 sshd: rui@pts/0 (sshd)
955 v0- I    0:00.00 sh /etc/rc autoboot
956 v0- I    0:00.00 logger -p daemon.notice -t fsck
958 v0- I    0:00.00 sleep 60
962 v0  Is+  0:00.01 /usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv0
963 v1  Is+  0:00.01 /usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv1
964 v2  Is+  0:00.01 /usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv2
965 v3  Is+  0:00.01 /usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv3
966 v4  Is+  0:00.01 /usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv4
967 v5  Is+  0:00.01 /usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv5
968 v6  Is+  0:00.01 /usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv6
969 v7  Is+  0:00.01 /usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv7
974  0  Is   0:00.02 -sh (sh)
976  0  I    0:00.08 su
977  0  S    0:00.04 _su (csh)
984  0  R+   0:00.01 ps ax
```